# Assigning User.Identity.Name to variable keeps being null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net identity in my asp.net core mvc core 5 project.

I have a controller, where I need to save the name and email of the currently logged in user in two variables.
So, I now have this controller action:

```
    public  string GetUser(string name)
    {
        string u = User.Identity.Name;

        if (u != null)
        {
            return u;
        }
    }
```

Right now, I'm simply trying to save the name of the current user in a variable.

I start the program in debug mode, while I am logged in.
I have a breakpoint exactly on the line `string u = User.Identity.Name;`.
If I hover hover `User.Identity.Name` then I can see that the expression evaluates to the name of the currently logged in user.

But when I then step over to the next line, I can see that `u` evaluates to null.
Thus the if statement evaluates to false and is not executed.

If I write the action like this instead:

```
    public  string GetUser(string name)
    {
        if (User.Identity.Name != null)
        {
            return User.Identity.Name;
        }

        return "what";
    }
```

Then everything works as it should.
Why is this? why can I not assign the currently logged in user to any variable?

Comment: First method will not execute and give compiler error, unless you are not posting exact code. The second method can be shortened to just return User.Identiy.Name, and why are you passing parameter name to method if it's never used?